# display image preview in Html

Tags: php, jquery, html, json, ajax

i want to display image after it upload

i write following code but it did't work

```
  onFileSuccess: function(file, response) {
        var json = new Hash(JSON.decode(response, true) || {});

        if (json.get('status') == '1') {
            file.element.addClass('file-success');
        } else {
            file.element.addClass('file-failed');

        }
    })
```

and li is

```
         <li class="file file-success">
         </li>
```

the file-success class is

```
     #img-list li.file.file-success {
background-image: url(uploading/assets/uploaded.png);
     }
```

and my php return image name after uploading like this

```
       $info1='../uploads/' . $newfilename; 
       $return['fpath'] = $info1;
```

in place of uploaded.png i want to show image with is return by php in

```
      $return['fpath'] = $info1; statement
```

Thanks

Comment: What are you using for file-upload? Have you looked in json array returned, if file name is there?

Answer (score 0):

Can you be more specific about what didn't work?

Is `file.element` a jQuery object or a plain DOM element? Perhaps you need to jQuerify it:

```
$(file.element).addClass('file-success');
```

Comment: yes its jquery object and its works and how the file-sucess class , but i dont know how to set image there

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how you have your elements set up, or what the json looks like, but it might be better to append the image itself to the `<li>` rather than setting it as a background.

```
onFileSuccess: function(file, response) {
                var json = new Hash(JSON.decode(response, true) || {});

                if (json.get('status') == '1') {
                        file.element.addClass('file-success');
                        file.element.append('<img src="' + json.get('filename') + '">'); 
                } else {
                        file.element.addClass('file-failed');

                }
        })
```